# How can i listen to custom service's event in socket.io android without feathers-client

Tags: feathersjs, socket.io-java-client

I have use featherjs in server-side, unfortunately , feathers-client in android not supported anymore.So , i think i need to use only socket.io-client to listen to  feathers serivce event, but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The direct [Socket.io API is documented here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#direct-connection) and the [listening to custom events section](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#listening-to-events) shows how to listen to a custom event:

```
socket.on('messages myevent', function(data) {
  console.log('Got myevent event', data);
});
```

Make sure [event channels](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html#publishing) are set up accordingly.